# Parsing server start time based on log file

Tags: regex, powershell, scripting

I am searching the following log file for errors and get a mail if true.

```
(DIAG:GENERAL)(01:02:07 28/12/2016)(FREE MEM.MB:248846)(USER:SYSTEM)(REMOTE:LOCAL)(Logger successfully started...)
(DIAG:GENERAL)(01:02:08 28/12/2016)(FREE MEM.MB:248878)(USER:SYSTEM)(REMOTE:LOCAL)(======================================)
(DIAG:GENERAL)(01:02:08 28/12/2016)(FREE MEM.MB:248878)(USER:SYSTEM)(REMOTE:LOCAL)(Starting 
(DIAG:GENERAL)(01:02:08 28/12/2016)(FREE MEM.MB:249051)(USER:SYSTEM)(REMOTE:LOCAL)(======================================)
(DIAG:GENERAL)(01:02:08 28/12/2016)(FREE MEM.MB:249057)(USER:SYSTEM)(REMOTE:LOCAL)(Class manager successfully initialized...)
(DIAG:GENERAL)(01:02:08 28/12/2016)(FREE MEM.MB:249069)(USER:SYSTEM)(REMOTE:LOCAL)(WinSock successfully initialized...)
(DIAG:GENERAL)(01:02:08 28/12/2016)(FREE MEM.MB:249069)(USER:SYSTEM)(REMOTE:LOCAL)(Thread manager successfully initialized...)
(DIAG:GENERAL)(01:02:08 28/12/2016)(FREE MEM.MB:249067)(USER:SYSTEM)(REMOTE:LOCAL)(Transaction subsystem successfully started...)
(DIAG:GENERAL)(01:04:29 28/12/2016)(FREE MEM.MB:201470)(USER:SYSTEM)(REMOTE:LOCAL)(Start init basis index reader... Name : )
(DIAG:GENERAL)(01:04:32 28/12/2016)(FREE MEM.MB:201470)(USER:SYSTEM)(REMOTE:LOCAL)(Stop  init basis index reader... Name :  Num : 655711255 Set : 655711255 + 
(DIAG:GENERAL)(01:04:46 28/12/2016)(FREE MEM.MB:200341)(USER:SYSTEM)(REMOTE:LOCAL)(...zipped 292527623 / 655711255 % 44.6123)
(DIAG:GENERAL)(01:05:03 28/12/2016)(FREE MEM.MB:200357)(USER:SYSTEM)(REMOTE:LOCAL)(...zipped 288669002 / 655711255 % 44.0238)
(DIAG:GENERAL)(01:14:35 28/12/2016)(FREE MEM.MB:202999)(USER:SYSTEM)(REMOTE:LOCAL)(RealTimeManager successfully launched... WIZZADOAS)
(DIAG:GENERAL)(01:14:35 28/12/2016)(FREE MEM.MB:202999)(USER:SYSTEM)(REMOTE:LOCAL)(PersistObjectCache initialize...COasStudiaFolderObject max = 1)
(DIAG:GENERAL)(01:14:35 28/12/2016)(FREE MEM.MB:202999)(USER:SYSTEM)(REMOTE:LOCAL)(Report Layout Manager init...)
(DIAG:GENERAL)(01:14:35 28/12/2016)(FREE MEM.MB:202999)(USER:SYSTEM)(REMOTE:LOCAL)(Report Packet Manager init...)
(DIAG:GENERAL)(01:14:35 28/12/2016)(FREE MEM.MB:202999)(USER:SYSTEM)(REMOTE:LOCAL)(Report Packet Parameter Manager init...)
(DIAG:GENERAL)(01:14:35 28/12/2016)(FREE MEM.MB:202999)(USER:SYSTEM)(REMOTE:LOCAL)(CommandManager successfully initialized...)
(DIAG:GENERAL)(01:14:36 28/12/2016)(FREE MEM.MB:202993)(USER:SYSTEM)(REMOTE:LOCAL)(PersistObjectCache initialize...COasHistoryTransactionObject max = 195069)
(DIAG:GENERAL)(01:14:36 28/12/2016)(FREE MEM.MB:202993)(USER:SYSTEM)(REMOTE:LOCAL)(ReferenceManager successfully initialized...)
(DIAG:GENERAL)(01:14:36 28/12/2016)(FREE MEM.MB:202993)(USER:SYSTEM)(REMOTE:LOCAL)(===================================)
(DIAG:GENERAL)(01:14:36 28/12/2016)(FREE MEM.MB:202993)(USER:SYSTEM)(REMOTE:LOCAL)(Server64 successfully started....)
(DIAG:GENERAL)(01:14:36 28/12/2016)(FREE MEM.MB:202993)(USER:SYSTEM)(REMOTE:LOCAL)(for exit please enter "q"...)
(DIAG:GENERAL)(01:14:36 28/12/2016)(FREE MEM.MB:202990)(USER:SYSTEM)(REMOTE:LOCAL)(Check the logfile for current state)
(DIAG:GENERAL)(01:14:36 28/12/2016)(FREE MEM.MB:202987)(USER:SYSTEM)(REMOTE:LOCAL)(===================================)
(DIAG:XMLRPC)(01:14:37 28/12/2016)(FREE MEM.MB:203014)(USER:SYSTEM)(REMOTE:10.67.125.250:3000)(XmlRpc: called member-method 'HandleEvent'.0)s ] = 1052239)
```

```
$a = Get-Content 'D:\log\server.log' | Select-String error

if (!($a -eq $null)) {
    $b = $a | Out-String
    Send-MailMessage -To $me -From $me -Subject "LIVE - Server ERRORs" -Body "$b" -Priority High -SmtpServer $smtp
}
```

So far, so good.
Now I would like to know how long the server took for the start process. 
The information is there in line

```
(DIAG:GENERAL)(01:02:07 28/12/2016)(FREE MEM.MB:248846)(USER:SYSTEM)(REMOTE:LOCAL)(Logger successfully started...)
```

and

```
(DIAG:GENERAL)(01:14:36 28/12/2016)(FREE MEM.MB:202993)(USER:SYSTEM)(REMOTE:LOCAL)(Server64 successfully started....)
```

but I don't know how to parse/compare it with RegEx.

Would appreciate help on this as RegEx is not so easy to understand, to be honest.

Comment: Soo you don't 100% need RegEx for this since it looks like the character positions will be consistent so if you want you can locate the lines using `-like` and then just use substrings to pull out the dates.  However if you are interested in learning RegEx paste your log into http://regexr.com and play around with the regex string until you are getting the matches you want(the reference library on the left is also wonderful)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Split the lines by `(` or `)` and take the 3rd thing to get the datetime, then parse it into a PowerShell datetime with the pattern: *hours:minutes:seconds day/month/year*:

```
$LoggerTime = Select-String 'logger successfully started' 'D:\log\server.log' | ForEach-Object { 

    [datetime]::ParseExact($_.Line.split('()')[3], 'HH:mm:ss dd/MM/yyyy', $null) 

}

$Server64Time = Select-String 'server64 successfully started' 'D:\log\server.log' | ForEach-Object { 

    [datetime]::ParseExact($_.Line.split('()')[3], 'HH:mm:ss dd/MM/yyyy', $null) 

}


Write-Host Server Startup took: ($Server64Time - $LoggerTime)

# e.g. Server Startup took: 00:12:29
```

When you subtract two `[datetimes]`, you get a `[TimeSpan]` for the duration.

NB. assumes each line only appears once in the log.

Answer (score 1):

You need to do two things:

- Extract the matching lines from the log file:

  ```
  $log   = Get-Content 'D:\log\server.log'
  $line1 = $log -match 'Logger successfully started'
  $line2 = $log -match 'Server64 successfully started'
  ```
- Extract the timestamp from each line:

  ```
  $ts = $line -replace '.*\((\d{2}:\d{2}:\d{2} \d{2}/\d{2}/\d{4})\).*', '$1'
  ```

  convert the timestamps to `DateTime` values:

  ```
  $culture = [Globalization.CultureInfo]::InvariantCulture
  $d = [DateTime]::ParseExact($ts, 'HH:mm:ss dd\/MM\/yyyy', $culture)
  ```

  and calculate the difference between the two values:

  ```
  $startupTime = ($d2 - $d1).TotalMinutes
  ```

Comment: Hi Ansgar, thank you for your help. I got it working like this:

Comment: I got it working but the result is 12:48 instead of 12:29 (how can I add my code here?)

Comment: @PaulSmith 12.48 minutes is the decimal representation of 12 minutes and 29 seconds (12:29 or 12'29").

Comment: Thank you for your help, appreciate it!!